# Different between arpspoof command spoof only target and both target and gateway

Tags: kali-linux, arp-spoofing

Is there any different on

**case 1**

```
arpspoof -i <interface> -t <target> <default gateway>
```

**case 2**

```
arpspoof -i <interface> -t <target> <default gateway>
arpspoof -i <interface> -t <default gateway> <target>
```

I found a lot of tutorial on website, some only spoof the target, while some spoof both target and gateway. I had tested both case and both work well. I just wonder is it for case one the arpspoof command will auto spoof the gateway? I would like to appreciate if you could explain both case a little bit more.

Thank you for your explanation and clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**case 1**
 - Will only tell the target that you are the router. If you don't tell the router that you are the target, the router will send packets to the target, the target will send the reply to you, and it will stop there. This will effectively DOS the target because you aren't forwarding the packets to the router.

**case 2**
 - Is the complete ARP spoofing process.
 - The first command tells the target you are the router.
 - The second command tells the router you are the target.

Case 2 should always be used for [MITM](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-middle_attack).